# How to display text from a string differently depending on preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Hi I have a string for example like:

````
$text = "this code does amazing things ```code goes here``` and some more ```more code``` what do you think about it?";
````

and I want to be able to display the code that is in the triple backticks in pre tags and the rest of the text normally like:

this code does amazing things
code goes here
and some more
more code
what do you think about it?

so far I am only able to display the code in the triple backticks and not the rest of the text.

my code so far:

````
    $text = "this code does amazing things ```code goes here``` and some more ```more code```  what do you think about it?";
  $pattern = '/```([^```]+)```/';

  preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
  echo implode('<pre></pre>', $matches[1]);
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`preg_replace`**](https://www.php.net/preg_replace)

````
<?php

$string = "this code does amazing things ```code goes here``` and some more ```more code``` what do you think about it?";

$str = preg_replace(
            '/([\`]{3})(.*?)([\`]{3})/',
            '<pre>$2</pre>',
            $string);
echo $str;
//Output: this code does amazing things <pre>code goes here</pre> and some more <pre>more code</pre> what do you think about it?
````

https://eval.in/205356

**Edit:** Showing HTML code within the `<pre>` tags.

You [**`preg_replace_callback`**](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) for this one.

````
$string = "this code does amazing things ```code goes here``` and some more ```<div class=\"color:red;\">Hello</div>``` what do you think about it?";

$str = preg_replace_callback(
            '/([\`]{3})(.*?)([\`]{3})/',
            function($matches) {
                $matches[2] = htmlentities($matches[2]);
                return '<div style="display: block;font-family: monospace;white-space: pre;margin: 1em 0px;">'. $matches[2] .'</div>';
            },
            $string);
echo $str;
````

https://eval.in/205434

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f04Er.png]

Comment: can you also suggest me how to build these `'/([\`]{3})(.*?)([\`]{3})/'` stuffs???

Comment: Thanks @Ronser. Use tools like [RegexOne](http://regexone.com/), [regular-expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), [RexEgg](http://www.rexegg.com/), [Read through these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+isaccepted%3Ayes)

Comment: would it be to much if I asked you to also tell me how to render code without it trying to execute inside the pre tags, i tried &lt; and &gt; in between the pre tags but the code then does not even show at all

Comment: @Blu3 Not at all. 15 minutes.

Comment: @Blu3 Updated answer. I hope that suits your needs.

Comment: YES now it shows the code but i tried for example entering some php code in it and php came up with an undefined variable notice, I want people to be able to insert all kinds of code without it being rendered if you know what I mean and thank you very much for taking your time to help me out, your awesome!!!

Comment: The issue is having `$string` in double quotes. You'd need to escape the variable. Ie. `echo \$var;`. Otherwise, change your input. I don't have much time at the moment to come up with a hack for this sort of thing, apologies.

Comment: no problem friend I ll try my best to find a hack for this, if by some chance later on you do have time to work your magic I would be very grateful. Thank you very much for all your help friend, your a life saver!.

Comment: Absolutely, I will. If you want to keep tabs on me, contact me via [*Twitter*](http://twitter.com/sniko_). Hopefully I'll have chance this weekend.